# Is there a website that shows equivalent views through different telescopes?

Tags: telescope

I'm trying to buy a beginners telescope. I have a Celestron TravelScope, but would like something better. When I look at other models, many users have posted images from their viewfinders. Is there a site that collates all of these, to give an idea of what I can expect from a given scope (e.g. is Mars just a red dot, can I make out Saturn's rings, what's the detail on the moon like, etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deep sky watch has an article that covers this

http://www.deepskywatch.com/Articles/what-can-i-see-through-telescope.html

It includes sample image of what can be seen in, for example, a medium telescope (150mm objective) with 180x magnification [image]

Answer (score 4):

The [astronomy.tools](http://astronomy.tools/) is a great site for visual and imaging "expectations".

Answer (score 3):

Not a website, but [Stellarium](https://stellarium.org) allows to show the view through different telescopes / different eye pieces or the view area of different sensors or through binoculars.

It comes with a selection of fairly usual eye pieces, telescopes and sensors and barlow lenses (if any), but you can always [add your own choice](http://stellarium.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Oculars_plugin) to each of these categories so that you can also preview exactly of what you want to compare, if you know exactly what to compare.

Answer (score 3):

On [Deep Sky Archive](http://www.deepsky-archive.com/) you can browse different views of the same object with different instruments and magnification; here you won't find any planet.

As of 2020 Deep Sky Archive no longer collects user observation, but it is available [Taivaanvahti observation database](https://www.taivaanvahti.fi/).
On this latest observation database you can search for Category "Solar System", 'saturn' on "Free text search" and browse the images, looking for those taken with a telescope (many of the photos are captured by smartphone).
For each observation, under "Technical information" section, you can read the instrument used to take that image.

Comment: I think it is not link-only (considering the question).